# Javascript innerHTML with Popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can't understand why this inner html script isn't working. I posted the javascript on jsFiddle. You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/JyV73/1/

I have two versions of the link. In the first the rewrite link is within a popup that needs to be closed and another opened with the proper text within the textarea.

In the second, there is just a link on the page that when it is clicked should hopefully open the popup with the proper text within wht textarea.

The only problem is that it doesn't work for the second version because of I must close the popup. If I comment out that first `document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none'` then the plain link works, so my first thought is to create two function. But since this javascript is part of a php template file that is included I think it would be simpler on the php code to just solve this using pure javascript.

I'm still learning javascript, and any help would be appreciated. I hope I was clear. Thank you so much.

HTML

```
<a href="#popup" rel="popup">open</a>

<div id="popup" class="popup"> <a href="#new" rel="popup" onClick="rewrite('popup', 'blah')">Rewrite</a>

</div>
<div id="new" class="popup">
    <textarea id="new-text"></textarea>
</div>
<!-- This is the stuff that doesnt work for some reason <a href="#new" rel="popup"         onClick="rewrite('popup', 'blah')">Rewrite</a>

<div id="new" class="popup">
<textarea id="new-text"></textarea>
</div>
-->
```

The Javascript

```
function rewrite(id, text) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('new-text').innerHTML = text;
}
```

Comment: Please include your code in the question, not just at jsfiddle.  Should that site ever go away, your question loses all context.

Comment: Okay I added the code to it. I just wanted to keep the question more concise

Comment: Hard to tell what doesn't work, when I click rewrite, I see the textarea with the value of 'blah', which seems to be exactly what you want? I'm also having a hard time understanding the two different cases you explained.

Comment: Sorry, the way I worded the question was confusing. This link doesn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/JyV73/7/ But if i comment out that first line in the rewrite function as I did here ( http://jsfiddle.net/JyV73/11/ ) it works. BUT if I do this, then the popup doesn't close when I have that version. Make sense? So I'm wondering if there's a way to make it work for both versions.

Comment: You do realize there's an error in the version that doesn't work right? `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null`. Please be sure to always check error message and post them here.

Comment: Sorry had to downvote the question, it's way too hard to understand what you're asking, consider rewording it. Maybe it's my feeble brain, but others don't seem to understand what you're trying to do either

Comment: But I still gave it a random try... Does this look like it's doing what you want? I just uncommented the HTML that was commented out and both rewrite links seem to do the job http://jsfiddle.net/JyV73/18/

Comment: @JuanMendes Don't worry mate, I'm struggling too!

Comment: Note, you shouldn't be trying to close a popup created by a plugin by just hiding it. There should be a method on the plugin to close it. For example, you have to hide the overlay also. Please document your rewrite function so we can try to understand what is going on. `rewrite` should not be responsible for closing the popup anyway... It should just rewrite, you're having your function depend on behavior that it doesn't control

Comment: It's a confusing problem I understand. I appreciate the effort to try and fix the problem though. I can't figure out what's wrong with it, but I'll keep at it. The console does return one error though that might help. It says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null `

Comment: @Alex I already told you about the error message, it's saying that `document.getElementById(id)` returned null because the id doesn't exist. I also have already told you this. Also, please add relevant information to the question, like the links to working and non-working version, don't make us read the comments to be able to understand something about the question

Comment: @Alex Why are you commenting out HTML?

Comment: Yeah, I've looked at just about enough as I understand of the question now. I've posted a link to a working version of your second goal (opens popup with textbox filled) though.

Comment: @Elliot I've posted a link that does that too... I'm not sure what the OP means when they say they must close the popup

Comment: @JuanMendes Yeah, me neither. I don't really understand the hybrid jQuery/regular JS approach either. Doesn't seem like the best way of doing it but I don't actually know anything about jQuery. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely clear on what you are trying to do here, but from the way I read your code you want to set the value of the text area to a specific value.

here is how you do that: http://jsfiddle.net/JyV73/9/

```
function rewrite(id, text) {
    $('#new-text').val(text);
}
```

You're not using pop-ups, you're using modals, which means its' a div inside the page that toggles visibility. You can access information from those components whether they are visible or not, fyi.

Still, Im not entirely sure on what you're trying to do here.

Comment: The `id` param is unused, should you remove it?

Comment: Also, you've got two text areas with the same id. Id's cannot be reused on the same page, only classes can.

Comment: Sure, you can remove the id for my example, but his goal is to pass in an id and set value to it. Here is my updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/JyV73/15/

Comment: What about the fact that he wanted to hide something else?

Comment: This solution works in jsFiddle. So I got excited fro a second, but when I use it on my actual site it doesn't close the modal that is open when I click the rewrite link that is within the modal. So I'm not sure what the issue is. I checked my jquery version it was identical. Any idea why it might be working in jsfiddle and not on my localhost. I realize it's a hard question but sometimes people have had similar problems before.

Comment: @Alex Your problem is that you haven't been able to create a good reduction of your problem, if it's fixed in JSfiddle it should work for you. Here's a tip, IDs are nasty, prevents you from ever reusing anything on a page...

Answer (score 0):

I changed `document.getElementById('new-text').innerHTML = text;` to `document.getElementById('new-text').value = text;` because it's the `value` attribute of the text box which you want to set.

Also each element on the page with an ID needs to have a unique ID (it seems like you might have been trying to reuse IDs at one point but maybe I'm wrong!)

I still haven't worked out exactly what you're trying to achieve but those changes *needed* to be made no matter what.

This code is sufficient to achieve your second goal though: http://jsfiddle.net/JyV73/19/

I added an `onClick` attribute (`onClick="rewrite('popup', 'blah')"`) to your "open" link to do the writing to the textbox. :)

Comment: I do have the id attribute on the popup box. It's just a coincidence that 'popup' is the name for both the id and the class

Comment: I don't really understand jsfiddle but I just changed the ID of that div to popup and clicked update and now it works

Comment: It was probably me that changed it if jsfiddle changes are applied to your version as well!

Comment: Well the way it is set up right now it works. That may be what is causing the confusion. But the commented html code doesn't work for some reason. So if you uncomment that you'll see what I'm talking about, and I can't figure out the reason for that.

Comment: @Alex On http://jsfiddle.net/JyV73/7/ there is no element with ID 'popup', it's commented out, that's why it was erroring out